GeoServer 2.25.2 not showing XML files in browser but download the XML file
We have upgraded from GeoServer 2.18.x to GeoServer 2.25.2 and we have a problem to open a .xml file in the browser.
Before upgrading the GeoServer it was possible to show/open the XML file in the browser, but now in GeoServer 2.25.2 the .xml file only downloaded, but we want to show it in the browser.
The location that is used for the .xml files: https://url/www/download/test.xml
.png/jpeg or .html files are open and show in the browser

That sounds like a browser configuration issue

You think it's not related to GeoServer 2.25.x and extra security? Because when i put the contents from the .xml and other needed files under /opt/tomcat/webapps/ then the xml is showing in the browser

We might have changed the mime types allowed but I doubt it - try fetching it with curl and look at the headers to see what the mime type is and if your browser is set to display that type

This is the output from curl -I

HTTP/1.1 200
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="nl.xml"
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 10:29:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 8490
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2024 10:29:57 GMT
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

So you need to configure your browser to open application/xml;

I have setup firefox to open application/xml in the browser, but that's not working. Strange thing is, that when i put the data folder included .xml in the webapps folder, tomcat serve the .xml file in the browser, but from GeoServer doesn't.
Is there a setting in GeoServer 2.25.x and above that .xml files only downloadable is?

I do not understand where do you have those xml files. Are they in your GeoServer data_dir?

I have put them in the /srv/geoserver_data/www/download folder. I can confirm that in GeoServer version 2.24.3 xml is showing in the browser, upgrade to higher it's only downloading.
